SQL Server 2016 upgrade
We need to upgrade our SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2019. We are also using replication for our test and production environments.
What my question is: what are the downfalls of upgrading from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2017 and then to SQL Server 2019, as opposed to just upgrading from SQL Server 2016 directly to SQL Server 2019?
We don't want to break production and want to have all of our plans in order before we do this. Please any suggestions would be helpful
I have done a bit of research on line and nothing that is talking about issues that might come up during the upgrades. Just pros and cons of each upgraded version

All these things are already described in the docs with migration instructions and planners for every feature. bit of research you won't find anything if people just don't do things this way. The only reason to go through an intermediate version is if there's no direct upgrade path. You can directly upgrade from 2016 to 2019

The actual choice you need to make is to upgrade in place or create a new server and restore the databases there. In almost all cases it's better to create a new server. Not only will you get new, better hardware but you'll also have the ability to fall back to the old server if anything goes wrong.

Thank you both! this gave me a good amount to think about
